# Compare data in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, inner-join, self-join

I have a table that stores monthly data and I would like to create a comparison between the quantity movement within a period.

Here is an example of the table

[image: a table with a client that can have one or more policies and each policy can have one or more funds. This is a one-to-many relationship].

The SQL statement below is meant to return any changes that has happened within a period - any fund/policy partial or total loss as well as partial or total gain. I have been battling with it for a while - any help would be well appreciated.

I currently have 5 sets of unions - (where the policies and funds match and there's a difference in quantities held, where the policies exist in the previous and not in the current and vice versa and where the securities exist in the previous and not in the current and vice versa) but the other unions work save for the last couple (where the securities exist in the previous and not in the current and vice versa). It doesn't seem to return every occurrence.

```
 SELECT distinct pc.[Client]
      ,pc.Policy
      ,cast(pc.Qty as decimal) AS CurrQ
      ,0 AS PrevQ
      ,cast(pc.Qty as decimal) - 0 AS QtyDiff
      ,CASE WHEN cast(pc.Qty as decimal) - 0 > 0 THEN 'Bought Units'
            WHEN cast(pc.Qty as decimal) - 0 < 0 THEN 'Sold Units'
          ELSE 'Unknown'
       END AS TransactionType
       ,convert(varchar,cast(pc.[ValDate] as date),103) AS CurrValDate
       ,'' AS PrevValDate
  FROM table pc
  WHERE convert(varchar,cast(pc.[ValDate] as date),103) = convert(varchar,getdate(),103)
  AND pc.Policy IN (SELECT policy
                    FROM table
                    WHERE convert(varchar(10),[ValDate],103) = convert(varchar(10),getdate()-1,103)

  AND pc.[Fund] NOT IN (SELECT PM.[Fund]
                        FROM table pc
                        LEFT JOIN table pm ON pc.policy = pm.policy
                        WHERE convert(varchar,cast(pc.[ValDate] as date),103) = convert(varchar,getdate(),103))
                        AND convert(varchar,cast(pm.[ValDate] as date),103) = convert(varchar,getdate()-1,103))
```

[image: omits the fghij fund (that didn't exist previously on the same policy) and pqrst that existed but was fully sold - see the highlighted rows.)]

Comment: In your second subquery, you have a `LEFT JOIN` to `table`, but then reference it in the `WHERE`; implicitly turning it into an `INNER JOIN`. Also, why are you converting the values of columns like `ValDate` to a `date` and then a `varchar` in the `WHERE`? That is going to ruin any performance you *did* have. Leave them as they are, the date & time datatype they were initially. And when you *do* need to convert to a `varchar` **always** declare your length.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the expected output that corresponds to our sample data.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for the comments. The table I posted is a dummy - in the exact file/table the formatting isn't a date but I take your point of specifying the length when converting to a varchar.

Comment: The table is a dummy? What does that have to do with your SQL `WHERE convert(varchar,cast(pc.[ValDate] as date),103) = convert(varchar,getdate(),103)`? That isn't your table, and if you aren doing that in your Query, then why is it in our "sample"?

Comment: @Larnu, what I meant was that it is a sample table - I won't be able to post the real data here due to regulations. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though as regards the where clause changing the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN but I believe you can be a bit more polite in your comments. I came here to ask because I didn't know but again, I am grateful - seems that was the issue. I'd check and report back. Cheers

Comment: I'm not being rude at all, I'm trying to understand why you're converting a date and time data type to a `date` and then a `varchar`. Doing so in your `WHERE` will have (significant) performance issues. If there is a good reason, the. I can likely direct a better way, that means that your indexes can be used and you don't lose (lots of) performance. When I asked about it though, you directed me to the sample data; which doesn't answr my question and why I was confused. The sample data and the reason for the`CONVERT` expressions shouldn't be related.

Comment: @Larnu, when you asked I told you that the main table wasn't a date field and that I just copied the code in to show - I didn't just direct you to my sample data and contrary to what you said about the sample data and the reason for using CONVERT isn't related is wrong because it was the sample data that made you think it was a date datatype but it's fine. Thanks for the pointer and like I said earlier, it is appreciated.Your pointer as regards the joins was the fix. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Larnu rightly mentioned in the comment section, the extra conditions in the query changed the run from a LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN. I changed the code to have policy, fund and date in the ON clause:

```
FROM table pc
LEFT JOIN table pm ON (pc.policy = pm.policy
                       AND pc.fund = pm.fund
                       AND pc.[ValDate]-1 = pm.[ValDate])
```

and got rid of the sub queries.

Thanks again Larnu.